# Magento 2 connection after moving

Tags: magento2, database, server-setup

I moved my website to a new server and :

1- Changed database connection *`app/etc/env.php`*

2- Cleared the
    cached files in "`/var/cache`", "`/var/page_cache`",
    "`var/view_preprocessed`","`/var/composer_home`", "`/var/generation`"

and i still got the following error:

> Error!: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'USER_XXXX'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Note: USER_XXXX is my old database user not the new one which is in my env file

Edit:

while runing the following commands

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/bin/php bin/magento cache:clean
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/bin/php bin/magento cache:flush
```

i got the following

> Warning: Uncaught Exception: Warning:
>   require(/home/btcegyptgold/public_html/setup/config/application.config.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/btcegyptgold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php
>   on line 57 in
>   /home/btcegyptgold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
>   Stack trace:
>
> 0 /home/btcegyptgold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(57):
>   Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'require(/home/b...',
>   '/home/btcegyptg...', 57, Array)
>
> 1 /home/btcegyptgold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(57):
>   require()
>
> 2 /home/btcegyptgold/public_html/bin/magento(22): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct('Magento CLI')
>
> 3 {main}   thrown in /home/btcegyptgold/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php
>   on line 61

Comment: just make sure in app/etc/env.php host, dbname, username and password's values are correct as per your new database server, Also try once in private window

Comment: When do the error displays ? On frontend or admin ?

Comment: it's in front, and database connection is corretct

Comment: Also note that the error displayed the old user connection not the one in file

Answer (score 0):

Run this and see if it works :

```
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} \;
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} \;

chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Comment: I did but it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have changed the credentials in `app/etc/env.php`.

Find this part and double check it:

```
 'db' => 
  array (
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'connection' => 
    array (
      'default' => 
      array (
        'host' => '[host]',
        'dbname' => '[dbname]',
        'username' => '[user]',
        'password' => '[password]',
        'active' => '1',
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

After, make sure you flush your cache! Also, if you are using Redis or Memcached, flush cache for those too.

---

If you are sure all the above is correct, the most probable issue will be that the database user have not enough "User Privileges" for the given database.

---

In regards to the new error you are getting, try to manually remove following:

```
var/generation
var/cache
var/view_preprocessed
var/page_cache
var/di
```

Also, try to give bin/magetno correct permissions:

```
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Comment: Note: the error and connection not the same user

Comment: Are you using redis or memcached? If so, remove the cache!

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: i already did before adding my post, but i don't have "var/di"

Comment: Try this? :P Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in past, cache flush works for me

login your server via ssh

and fire below command

```
cd /YourMagentoPath
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: I got the same error above